# xxd with 64 bit addresses

Tags: files, xxd

I find xxd to be nice and convenient for simple manipulation of binary data in the terminal. However it has a limitation in that all addresses outputted by the program is limited to 32 bits. E.g.

```
root:/# xxd -s 0x5baae0000 /dev/sda
baae0000: 2d7c 6176 6976 6172 7c61 7469 7a61 720a  -|avivar|atizar.
```

Notice the 5 at the beginning is gone. This means that using this directly with `xxd -r` will end up patching a region over 10 billion bytes earlier than what I want. In other words I want to e.g. do this,

```
root:/# echo HELLO | xxd -o 0x5baae0000 | xxd -r - /dev/sdb
```

but I end up having to work around this by doing something like this,

```
root:/# echo HELLO | xxd -o 0x5baae0000 | xxd -r -seek 0x500000000 - /dev/sdb
```

which adds back the missing 0x5000000 bytes offset into the target file when parsing the patch.

---

In any case I want to know if there is either a unknown/clever way to have xxd use 64 bit addresses or an alternative program that operates like xxd without these limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A patch with a fix for the issue has now been officially included as a part of vim as patch [854](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/d8c56a0d29ccb53e12c6dec73b9a0e8a6dad99c2). So either try to update to a newer version of vim (v8.1.0854+) that includes the patch or compile from [source](https://github.com/vim/vim) yourself if not yet available.

Answer (score 2):

[`xxd` uses `long`s for the address but explicitly truncates it to 32bit](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/79cf7c0d4574f15cfad5ad706f175e226c528f2a/src/xxd/xxd.c#L814) and there doesn't seem to be any way around that. That's [vim issue #3791](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/3791) (thanks for reporting it), [now fixed in patch 8.1.0854](/a/497955).

It doesn't however seem it ever had that limitation on input (with `-r`), so you can use standard `od` to print the hex dump:

```
od -j 0x5baae0000 -Ax -vtx1 -N16 /dev/sda
```

Which will output something like:

```
5baae0000 2d 7c 61 76 69 76 61 72 7c 61 74 69 7a 61 72 0a
5baae0010
```

However note that several `od` implementations, including GNU `od`¹ don't *seek* to reach the offset specified by `-j` but read and skip all the data which makes it impractical for a large block device like in your case.

Or if you care about the ASCII side, using BSD `hexdump`'s

```
$ hexdump -ve '"%_ax:" 16/1 " %02x"' -e '"  " 16 "%_p" "\n"' -s 0x5baae0000 -n 16 /dev/sda
5baae0000: 2d 7c 61 76 69 76 61 72 7c 61 74 69 7a 61 72 0a  -|avivar|atizar
```

Both of which you can feed to `xxd -r`

You can actually reproduce `xxd`'s output format (without the 32 bit address limitation) with `hexdump` with:

```
hexdump -ve '"%08_ax: " 2/1 "%02x"" " 2/1 "%02x"" " 2/1 "%02x"" " 2/1 "%02x"" "
                        2/1 "%02x"" " 2/1 "%02x"" " 2/1 "%02x"" " 2/1 "%02x"
            ' -e '"  " 16/1 "%_p" "\n"'
```

Neither `od` nor `hexdump` support an equivalent of `xxd`'s `-o` to offset the address, but you could always post-process their output to add the offset to the address fields with for instance:

```
perl -pe 's/^\w+/sprintf "%08x", 0xabcdef + hex$&/e'
```

In any case, to write data at specific offset into a file, you don't need `xxd`, you can use `dd`:

```
echo HELLO | dd bs=1 seek="$((0x5baae0000))" of=/dev/sda
```

Or `ksh93` `>#((...))` seeking operator:

```
echo HELLO 1<> /dev/sda >#((0x5baae0000))
```

or `zsh`'s `sysseek` builtin:

```
zmodload zsh/system
{
  sysseek -u 1 $((0x5baae0000)) &&
    echo HELLO
} 1<> /dev/sda
```

You can also use `xxd` with a 0 offset and use dd/ksh93/zsh to do the *seeking*:

```
echo HELLO | xxd | { sysseek -u 1 $((0x5baae0000)) && xxd -r; } 1<> /dev/sda
```

or:

```
echo HELLO | xxd | { dd bs=1 seek="$((0x5baae0000))" count=0 && xxd -r; } 1<> /dev/sda
```

---

<sup>¹ Looking at [the source](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/daaae12e3b56ebc51202f5b4d5b40be61982cd81/src/od.c#L1034), GNU `od` uses `fstat()` to get the size of the input (instead of `lseek(SEEK_END)`) so as not seek past the end of the file, which on systems like Linux where `st_size` doesn't reflect the size of the block device doesn't work for block devices</sup>

Comment: This doesn't capture the problem at all, sorry. It's the intermediate format of xxd I need (save it, manipulate it, use it). It's not actually writing e.g. «HELLO» to a specific location in a file that is the problem. I even gave an example myself how I could do it. Thanks for pointing out relevant code though.

Comment: @Christer, see edit.

Comment: `od` does not support seek and took 50 seconds to read those 16 bytes. `hexdump` on the other hand is almost perfect, though please also add `-v` to your answer. Sadly doesn't seem hexdump have an analogue to `xxd -o` which it a big bummer. Still going to mark this as accepted for now, thank you. :)

Comment: @Christer, see edit.